# Extend wifi network from one building to the next, making a new public network that cannot access machines on the original network

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

We have a secure wifi network at church in the main building. We now want to add an open wifi network in our hall across the drive way. The wifi signal makes it over to the hall, but barely. I got a wifi extender, and that works to get wifi over there, but I can see all the computers in the church office.

The wifi modem in the church building is an ATT UVerse and it does not have any settings to create a second SSID.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it securely without equipment that supports it.

1. Buy a pair of 2013 802.11ac AirPort Extremes. They have great bandwidth and range, support all the features you need, and are easy to configure. 2 @ $180 = $360
2. Disable Wi-Fi, NAT, and DHCP Server in the AT&T U-verse box. You basically want it to just act as a transparent bridging broadband modem, and have it talk only to your main AirPort Extreme.
3. Hook one AirPort Extreme's WAN port to a LAN port of the AT&T U-verse box.
4. If you had anything else connected to the LAN ports of the AT&T U-verse box, connect them to the LAN ports of the AirPort Extreme instead. If you need additional ports, use a small Ethernet switch.
5. Configure that main AirPort Extreme for NAT and DHCP service, Guest Network, and "Allow this network to be extended".
6. Hook the other AirPort Extreme up in the hall across the driveway. Configure it to extend the other network. Enable Guest Network on it as well.

The remote AirPort Extreme's Guest Network will be tunneled in a VLAN across the wireless backhaul links between buildings, and the main AirPort Extreme will route traffic from that VLAN out to the Internet without letting it get to your private (church office) LAN resources.

You could possibly set up the same stuff if your AT&T U-verse box could do guest network VLANs and stuff, or if you could run something like DD-WRT on it (and on the extender) to get that functionality. But the cost of the time it takes to get that working if you haven't done it before or aren't already a DD-WRT and VLAN wiz, would probably pale in comparison to the $360 that you'd pay for the pair of AirPort Extremes.